# multiprocessing Error in Python 3.6.5 that doesn't occur in 3.6.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

**This works in 3.6.1**

```
import multiprocessing

def test1(txt1):
    print(txt1)

txt1 = 'txt here'
test = multiprocessing.Process(target=test1, kwargs={"txt1": txt1})
test.start()
```

**Same code fails in 3.6.5 with:**

```
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

**This works in 3.6.5**

```
import multiprocessing

def test1(txt1):
    print(txt1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    txt1 = 'txt here'
    test= multiprocessing.Process(target=test1, kwargs={"txt1": txt1})
    test.start()
```

I have a more complicated directory structure and need to start the `process` outside of the `__main__` with something like this ...

**one.py**

```
import two
two.call3('txt here')
```

**two.py**

```
import three
import multiprocessing

def call3(txt1):
    test= multiprocessing.Process(target=three.test1, kwargs={"txt1": txt1})
    test.start()
```

**three.py**

```
def test1(txt1):
    print(txt1)
```

How can I get this to work instead of returning the error message above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution, I'm still testing if it will work with even more complex code design but looks like it solves the issue.

**one.py**

```
import two

if __name__ == '__main__':
    two.call3('txt here')
```

For freezing, adding `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` to **one.py** is probably i good idea as the error message suggests, but otherwise the code seems to run without it.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably rethink your decision of having code executing on `import`. As a workaround, something like this should work (assuming `one.py` is your main file):

**one.py**

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.freeze_support()

import two
two.call3('txt here')
```

Comment: Thanks, **one.py** is the main file but the example you provided doesn't work. Even if I keep everything in one file. Your suggested workaround having `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` in the import section does work ... but the same error is triggered because the `test= multiprocessing.Process(target=test1, kwargs={"txt1": txt1})` is not located inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` (worked fine before 3.6.5)